# Eliminación dinámica de ancestros

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un contenedor con algunas filas y dentro de ellas un div que contiene botones, uno de estos botones es para eliminar item. Todos los botones tienen las mismas clases y Ids. lo que quiero hacer es que al presionar el botón a través de javascript se elimine el contenedor abuelo y su contenido.

Este es el ejemplo de HTML.

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div id="loOrdenadoItems">
        <div class="row  mb-1" style="background-color:bisque">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-8" >
                algo
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" id="btnChangeOrder">Change</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="btnDelOrder">-</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mb-1" style="background-color:aqua">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-8">
                algo
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" id="btnChangeOrder">Change</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="btnDelOrder">-</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es el javascript que estaba escribiendo; capturar el evento y tratar de ingresar en una variable la información de "this" que sería el presionado y luego de ello identificar al padre y al abuelo y proceder a la eliminación pero **no sé como seguir**. Alguna idea / solución?;

```
$('#btnDelOrder').on('click', function () {
    try {
        var lst = $('#btnDelOrder').this
        //var lst = $('#btnDelOrder').(this).parentNode().css("background-color", "red");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está descrito por ti mismo:

> Todos los botones tienen las mismas clases y Ids.

Los [ID deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id), `$('#btnDelOrder')` te va a devolver solo el primer elemento que coincida con el selector.

Asigna el evento por clase y no por ID, de preferencia, incluyendo el contenedor general:

```
$('.card-body .btn-danger').on('click', function () {
    try {
        // $(this) es el botón que recibió clic, usa closest() para llegar al ancestro
        // Especifica etiqueta y clase del contenedor deseado
        let lst = $(this).closest('div.mb-1');
        $(lst).css("background-color", "red");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: mi error era conceptual, yo estaba pensando como que si el id iba a ser tratado como si fuera una clase, con tus cambios funciona y puedo identificar el elemento. Me salvaste maestro.